# parse twitter status with json php

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am trying to parse a twitter user stats (with php) -- I am pretty unfamiliar with parsing json so this is giving me a bit of a headache (I'm missing something silly here I know). I've looked at a bunch of answers/posts from others but can't quite peg it. Any help is appreciated.

Essentially what i want to get is the [url] and the [text] but I keep getting errors in php.

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
        [retweet_count] => 0
        [id_str] => 180735710897250304
        [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
        [geo] => 
        [favorited] => 
        [user] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id_str] => 46023
                [id] => 460
            )

        [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
        [truncated] => 
        [contributors] => 
        [source] => Facebook
        [entities] => stdClass Object
            (
                [hashtags] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [urls] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [expanded_url] => http://www.buzzfeed.co
                                [url] => http://t.c
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 0
                                        [1] => 20
                                    )

                                [display_url] => buzzfeed.com/c
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [expanded_url] => http://fb
                                [url] => http://t.
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 21
                                        [1] => 41
                                    )

                                [display_url] => fb.m
                            )

                    )

                [user_mentions] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [coordinates] => 
        [retweeted] => 
        [id] => 180735
        [created_at] => Fri Mar 16 19:22:06 +0000 2012
        [possibly_sensitive] => 
        [place] => 
        [text] => http://t.co
```

Comment: Could you please post the code you're using to get this output?

Answer (score 1):

The [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function takes an optional 2nd parameter to return an associative array instead of an object.

Try:
`json_decode($your_json_var, false)`

Then, you can just retrieve the values normally as you would with any array.

Comment: Yup knew this but was trying to get around it for one reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the values as below for example:

```
 echo $tweets[0]->id_str;
```

This will display the id_str value from your json data.